# Is this assertion: $¬[∃x\ ∃y\ ∃z \ (x ≤ y ≤ z)]$ equivalent to this: $∀x\ ∀y\ ∀z\ (x>y>z)$?

Tags: logic

> Is this assertion: $¬[∃x\ ∃y\ ∃z \ (x ≤ y ≤ z)]$ equivalent to this: $∀x\ ∀y\ ∀z\ (x>y>z)$?

Comment: No, it is not equivalent.

Comment: @LinAlg Why? I just negated it.

Comment: @user550202 $(x\leq y\leq z)\equiv(x\leq y\wedge y\leq z)$

Comment: So $(x\leq y \leq z)$ is equivalent to $(x\leq y \land y \leq z)$. If you negate that you have $(x>y \lor y>z)$

Comment: @user550202 - Note that $\lnot (x \leq y)$ is equivalent to $x > y$ if and only if the order $\leq$ is total.

Comment: What is the domain of $x, y, and of z$?  Without knowing that, or telling us that piece of missing information, whether $\lnot (x\leq y) \to  x>y$ or (note Godel's answer) $\lnot (x\leq y) \not\to  x>y,$ depends on the domain in which $x, y$ reside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The negation of $x \le y \le z$ is not $ x > y > z$:

Note first that $x \le y \le z$ is a shorthand for $(x \le y) \land (y \le z)$.
So we have to apply de Morgan to the negation and we thus get

$\lnot(x \le y) \lor \lnot(y \le z)$ which is (*in a linear order!*) $(x > y) \lor (y > z)$, while $x > y > z$ is shorthand for $(x > y) \land (y > z)$.

Comment: $\neg(x\leq y)$ is not equivalent to $x>y$. See my answer.

Comment: @Gödel I assumed the OP worked in a linear order, or his question would make less sense.

Comment: I don't understand why "the question would make less sense". This is a good excercise for understand the concep of order.

Comment: Have you heard the tale of "assume", @HennoBrandsma?  "To assume anything makes an as$*$ out of *u* and *me*."  (It's actually a good mnemonic for remembering how to spell "ass-u-me"

Comment: @amWhy Why a mnemonic for the word derived from "ad-sumere".. ( I studied Latin for 5 years)...

Comment: Well, it's a good mnemonic for those learning how to write the word in English. Okay...   for "ad-sumere" we can remember "ad[d]-sum[h]ere", then dropping the bracketed letters.  But that's less relevant to your use of "assume" in your first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{align}
\lnot \big [(\exists x)(\exists y)(\exists z)(x\leq y\leq z)\big]
\longleftrightarrow &
\lnot \big [(\exists x)(\exists y)\big(\exists z)\big((x\leq y) \mbox{ and } (y\leq z)\big)\big]
\\
\longleftrightarrow &
(\forall x)(\forall y)(\forall z)\lnot\big((x\leq y) \mbox{ and } (y\leq z)\big)
\\
\longleftrightarrow &
(\forall x)(\forall y)(\forall z)\big(\lnot(x\leq y) \mbox{ or } \lnot(y\leq z)\big)
\end{align}

As Godel observed in the case of an exercise in logic, we do not know whether $\leq$ is a relation of total order. But if we know that $\leq $ is a relation of total order then we can affirm that $\lnot (x\leq y )\longleftrightarrow $y

$$
\lnot \big [(\exists x)(\exists y)(\exists z)(x\leq y\leq z)\big]
\longleftrightarrow 
(\forall x)(\forall y)(\forall z)\big((x> y) \mbox{ or } (y> z)\big)
$$

Comment: $\neg(x\leq y)$ is not equivalent to $x>y$. See my answer.

Comment: Dear, @Gödel. It is understood that this is a relation of total order.

Comment: As is a logic excercise, I think that is in general. In the OP question is not clear if $\leq$ is a total order.

Comment: @Gödel Rethinking better, I see that you are correct. I put a caveat in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if wrong:

The negation should read:

For all $x$, for all $y$, for all $z$, the statement $x \le y \le z $ is not true.

Statement $x \le y \le z$ is equivalent to:

$x \le y$ AND $y \le z$.

Negation of this statement:

$x \gt y$ OR $y \gt z$.

The complete negation reads:

For all $x$, for all $y$, for all $z$,
$x\gt y$ or $y \gt z$.

P.S.As user Goedel and others point out we are dealing with a total order.

Comment: $\neg(x\leq y)$ is not equivalent to $x>y$. See my answer.

Comment: Goedel.Thank you.What do you suggest?Add total order?

Comment: Yes, this must be a total order.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The negation of $x\leq y$ is not $x>y$ in all context.

Consider $A:=\{a,b,c\}$ and $\leq:=\{(a,a);(b,b);(c,c);(a,b);(a,c)\}$.

Here you have that $\neg(b\leq c)$ is true but this does **not** imply that $(c<b)$.

Comment: +1 by precision and generality. I find it unfair to attribute "-1" to this answer.

Comment: @MathOverview thanks!

Comment: Interesting answer+.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not .

In the context of all real numbers your  $$∀x\ ∀y\ ∀z\ (x>y>z)$$

should have been $$∀x\ ∀y\ ∀z\ (x>y \text { or } y>z)$$

Comment: $\neg(x\leq y)$ is not equivalent to $x>y$. See my answer.

Comment: Are we talking about all real numbers in OP question?

Comment: In the question this is not clear. If this is a logic excercise, I think that is in general.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Why not think about what these sentences say in words?

The first: "You can't find three numbers weakly increasing in order".

The second: "Any arrangement of three numbers puts them in strictly decreasing order".

Common sense can help you avoid errors in formal manipulation of symbols.